# Sensethising domains

Tags: regex, perl

So I'm trying to put all numbered domains into on element of a hash doing this:

```
### Domanis ###
my $dom = $name;
$dom =~ /(\w+\.\w+)$/; #this regex get the domain names only
my $temp = $1;

if ($temp =~ /(^d+\.\d+)/) { # this regex will take out the domains with number 
    my $foo = $1;
    $foo = "OTHER";
    $domain{$foo}++;
}
else {
    $domain{$temp}++;
}
```

where `$name` will be something like:

```
something.something.72.154
something.something.72.155
something.something.72.173
something.something.72.175
something.something.73.194
something.something.73.205
something.something.73.214
something.something.abbnebraska.com
something.something.cableone.net
something.something.com.br
something.something.cox.net
something.something.googlebot.com
```

My code currently print this:

```
72.175
73.194
73.205
73.214
abbnebraska.com
cableone.net
com.br
cox.net
googlebot.com
lstn.net
```

but I want it to print like this:

```
abbnebraska.com
cableone.net
com.br
cox.net
googlebot.com
OTHER
lstn.net
```

where `OTHER` is all the numbered domains, so any ideas how?

Comment: Where do you get `lstn.net` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't need to split the variable into two, e.g. this regex will match the case you want to trap:
`/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/` -- returns true if the string ends with two 1-3 long digits separated by a dot

but I mean if you only need to separate those domains that are not numbered you could just check the last character in the domain whether it is a letter, because TLDs cannot contain numbers, so you would do something like
`/\w$/` -- if returns true, it is not a numbered domain (providing you've stripped spaces and new lines)

But I suppose it is better to be more specific in the regex, which also better illustrates the logic you are looking for in your script, so I'd use the former regex.

And actually you could do something like this:

```
if (my ($domain) = $name =~ /\.(\w+.\w+)$/)
{
#the domain is assigned to the variable $domain
} else {
#it is a number domain
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take what it currently puts, and use the regex:

```
/\d+\.\d+/
```

if it matches this, then its a pair of numbers, so remove it.

This way you'll be able to keep any words with numbers in them.

Answer (score 0):

Please, please indent your code correctly, and use whitespace to separate out various bits and pieces. It'll make your code so much easier to read.

Interestingly, you mentioned that you're getting the wrong output, but the section of the code you post has no `print`, `printf`, or `say` statement. It looks like you're attempting to count up the various domain names.

If these are the value of `$name`, there are several issues here:

```
if ($temp =~ /(^d+\.\d+)/) {
```

Matches nothing. This is saying that your string starts with one or more letter `d` followed by a period followed by one or more digits. The `^` anchors your regular expression to the beginning of the string.

I think, but not 100% sure, you want this:

```
if ( $temp =~ /\d\.\d/ ) {
```

This will find all cases where there are two digits with a period in between them. This is the sub-pattern to `/\d+\.\d+/`, so both regular expressions will match the same thing.

The

```
$dom =~ /(\w+\.\w+)$/;
```

Is matching anywhere in the entire string `$dom` where there are two letters, digits. or underscores with a decimal between them. Is that what you want?

I also believe this may indicate an error of some sort:

```
my $foo = $1;
$foo = "OTHER";
$domain{$foo} ++;
```

This is setting `$foo` to whatever `$dom` is matching, but then immediately resets `$foo` to `OTHER`, and increments `$domain{OTHER}`.

We need a sample of your initial data, and maybe the actual routine that prints your output.